# Using a Mac, is there any way to purchase iPad-only HD content from iTunes?

Tags: itunes

There are many movies on iTunes that only have HD versions if you are shopping from an iPad or Apple TV. However, I use a Mac Mini for my media center rather than an Apple TV. Is there any way to buy HD versions of these movies directly on a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3209

> In order to purchase, rent, and view HD content from the iTunes Store
>   on your computer, you need to have the latest version of iTunes
>   installed, you can download the latest version here. In addition, you
>   will need to have components that support HDCP (High-bandwidth Digital
>   Content Protection) installed on your computer.
>
> Mac System Requirements for HD content:
>
> - Mac OS X v10.5 or later iTunes 10 or later
> - 2.0 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo or faster processor
> - At least 1 GB of RAM 
>     A display that supports HDCP with a screen resolution of 1024x768 or
>     higher.
>
> If your computer does not meet all of the above requirements, you will be unable to 
>   purchase, rent, or view HD content from the iTunes Store.
>
> Note: If you are trying to view HD video on an external display, the
>   display must have a digital connection (DVI, DisplayPort, or HDMI) and
>   also support HDCP.

If it isn't obvious where to buy the movies, I would guess that your system requirements are not there.

Comment: Some movies do not show HD versions if viewed through iTunes on Mac. See, for instance: http://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/napoleon-dynamite/id270007388. On 2 year-old Macs with up-to-date 10.6 and 10.7, I see "Also available in HD on iPad and Apple TV".

Comment: I don't think that you can buy the HD Versions if they are not listed, for iTunes will detect whether your system cannot handle it... If your system can handle it, then that is an iTunes problem. I doubt that Apple would try to hide potential purchases from people.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's a licensing issue: for whatever misguided reason, the rights holders only want it purchasable on those devices. That's what I'm looking to bypass: I want to watch HD on my big TV, not a little iPad!

Comment: You can stream from your TV to your Mac/TV... I know, it is frustrating though. iOS5 will have Airplay, the software that allows you to do this included, but there are 3rd party solutions as well.